# Installing scipy in Ubuntu

Tags: python, installation

So whenever I try

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

I get:

```
ImportError: libatlas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I made sure I have `atlas-base` in my `/usr/lib/` dir. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: clarifications, I'm doing this in a virtualenv.

Edit 2: Someone suggested me to use `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` and this is what I get when I try to import:

```
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
    ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf: undefined symbol: ATL_chemv
```

Edit 3: After fixing some dependencies issue with numpy, I now get:

```
   import fblas
ImportError: libatlas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: why not use the repo? sudo apt-get install python-scikits-learn

Comment: I'm doing this in a virtual-env. Would that work?

Comment: Try `import numpy` or `import scipy`, if you still get same error, `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` may help you. It works for me.

Comment: Installing the right `scipy` is key.  If you're working in a python virtual env, try running `pip install -UI scipy`

Answer (score 4):

To get the dependencies try

`sudo apt-get install python python-dev libatlas3-base-dev gcc gfortran g++`

Also, you should check that numpy is up to date:

> >> import numpy
>
> >> numpy.version.version
>
> '1.6.1'

(for example). I think you want numpy > 1.5.0 for the latest scipy distribution.

Then you can try the `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` command suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install python-sklearn

Edit:

```
hdante@aielwaste:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

Comment: same import error

Comment: sorry, I answered without considering any kind of sandboxing. You might need to consider to reload your virtual environment with the new installed packages.

Comment: reloading virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

Comment: yea, I still get the Import error

Answer (score -1):

I can work by

```
echo "/usr/lib/atlas-base" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-lib.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Thanks for this thread:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52703/using-atlas-from-scipy